# Alter path of find result

Tags: bash, find, rename, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manipulate file name piped from find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60404/manipulate-file-name-piped-from-find-command)

How can I alter the path of a file found with `find` before I run an `exec` on it? I want to find files and then `mv` them to a mounted file system that has the same file structure as the system being searched.

Say I found `./home/usr1/dir1/file`, I want to move it to `/mountedSystem/home/usr1/dir1/file`, so all I need is to remove the leading `.` and append `/mountedSystem` to the start of the file path before executing the `mv`. Is there any way to do this safely?

Comment: why not just use the full path in your `find` command?

Comment: I want to move what I found to the equivalent position on the mounted file system. So I need to change the destination path which will be the same other than the first directory.

Comment: oh, i understand now.  use `rsync` instead of `find ... -exec`. `rsync` synchronizes file systems/directories

Comment: That looks good, can I specify only files that match a particular pattern/type like `find` or does it sync the whole system?

Comment: you can specify with wildcards, etc.  the man page should have everything you need

Answer (score 1):

`/./` in a middle of a path does nothing. You do not have to remove the dot:

```
find . -exec mv {} /mountedSystem/{} \;
```

Comment: Please be careful when batting around phrases like "does nothing"... `cd // ; pwd ; readlink -f .`

Comment: @ChrisDown Please read the answer carefully before commenting on it ;-) `cd /./ ; pwd ; readlink -f .`

Comment: @danielkullmann So? `.` does not always "do nothing", it does not always return the current pwd. Such a categorical statement is misleading.

Comment: @ChrisDown: I meant a path containing `/./`. Better now?

Comment: Thanks this works for my specified problem, but in terms of the question, is there a way to alter the path, for example, if I wasn't able to use the leading part of it and it had to change?

Comment: @Aaron: You can write a script that provides the change and then run it in `exec`. In the script, you can use Parameter Expansion or `sed`.